# This dependency was not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frameworks, frontend

When i try to `npm run serve` it stops at 98% and :

```
ERROR  
Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                   
This dependency was not found:

* @/components/HelloWorld.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/components/HelloWorld.vue
```

I looked up for some sources but never helped. Even installing HelloWorld.vue turns an error.

Comment: We need a little more context, which version are you running, what are you using for building, where are you referring to the HelloWorld component.

My guess is that you are trying to import HelloWorld component with the alias `@` but for some reason you don't have the alias setup, try to import it without the alias

Comment: `@/components` looks like a custom alias

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your files is trying to load a local component called `HelloWorld.vue` and it may not exist in your project structure. You shouldn't try to "install" it, but rather head to the `Home.vue` file where this error is being triggered from (see `Home.vue` at th end of the error message?). Then ask yourself, do you actually want to load `HelloWorld.vue`?

I imagine you're following some sort of "getting started with Vue" guide and you've been instructed to include that file. You'll have to either create that file in the `{YOUR_PROJECT}/src/components/` folder, or remove the code that's trying to load it.

Alternatively, this could be a configuration error in which you're trying to use the `@` alias but it hasn't been setup in webpack properly. Please include more info if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Vue Js cli is not installed on server

```
// to install vue on ubuntu
npm install -g @vue/cli
// check if it was installed successfully
vue --version
@vue/cli 4.1.2
```